# how can i add multiple="multiple" to select option

Tags: jquery

```
 <select id="months">
        <option value="1">January</option>
        <option value="2">February</option>
        <option value="3">March</option>
        <option value="4">April</option>
        <option value="5">May</option>
        <option value="6">June</option>
        <option value="7">July</option>
        <option value="8">August</option>
        <option value="9">September</option>
        <option value="10">October</option>
        <option value="11">November</option>
        <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>
```

How can I add multiple="multiple" into this select option with jquery. I am changing the dropdown into checkbox using the multiple-select-master.

Comment: http://api/jquery.com/prop or better yet, change the HTML directly.

Comment: you didn't try anything but asked the question directly. -1 for the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#months').prop('multiple', 'multiple');
```

Comment: @Gracy Mon - I am happy to see that, and I would be even happier if you accepted my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp) you don't actually need that attribute to have a value.

In order to add that attribute without a value, this should do:

```
$('#months').attr('multiple','')
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/traceline/vLnz385c/1/)

HTH